# Single or multiple rails projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm new to rails development so this is a very basic question. I'm working on a company website. The company makes several products customers can sign up for. The products are all very different. Should I create each as a separate rails app/project? Or should I build them all in one?

Apologies if this sounds stupid I'm new to MVC on the web (although I've been doing it on desktop/mobile for 4 years) and still learning the fundamentals of rails development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only reason you'd need to use separate apps is if you want some core system (like your database) or your Gemfile to be tailored to a specific product's needs.  This would only be necessary if you have vastly different and specific requirements for each product.  Else building one products app with separate db tables and MVCs for each product sounds like the way to go.

Comment: It sounds like doing it separately might be the best thing. The two products are completely different. The only connection is that they will be built by the one company and login will happen through the company website. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, when you said "sign up for product" I was assuming it was just the sign up app you were building but it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: No problem, your answer was helpful! Thanks